# add error in a method would not validate activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model `Account` and a method `withdraw`. I want to validate if the user has enough funds available, so I tried to `errors.add` directly into the `withdraw` method

```
def withdraw(amount)
  if balance < amount
    errors.add(:insufficient_funds, "You don't have enough funds.")
  end

  self.balance = balance - amount
end
```

While it does add the message to `errors` it doesn't prevent from saving. So I've changed my code. Here is my updated code:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validate :have_enough_funds

  def deposit(amount)
    self.balance = balance.to_f + amount.to_f
  end

  def withdraw(amount)
    @old_balance = balance.to_f
    @withdraw_amount = amount.to_f

    self.balance = @old_balance - @withdraw_amount
  end

  private

  def have_enough_funds
   return unless @withdraw_amount && @old_balance

   if @withdraw_amount > @old_balance
     errors.add(:insufficient_funds, "You don't have enough funds.")
   end
  end
end
```

I'm wondering why my first approach didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/17ef58db1776a795c9f9e31a1634db7bcdc3ecdf/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L334) might help you understand.

As you can see, when asking if an object is `valid?`, rails clears errors first.

As you were adding your errors outside of the validation flow, errors would be cleared, then validations ran, and no errors would be found.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid clearing the errors? So I can have simpler code

Comment: @like2learn I wouldn't recommend messing with such a basic feature of how Rails work. You will have much better luck in the long-run if you rethink how you approach this problem you're having.